# li from the image/icon

Tags: html, css

I want to hear about how I put the text to be straight out from the picture which is like the roof,

**CSS:**

```
ul.bruger {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
.login {
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('/img/topmenu/login.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    backgroud-position: 0px 0px; /* ret til så det passer */
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    margin: 2px;
}
.login p {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bruger">
<li class="login"><p>Login</p></li>
<li class="login"><p>Make</p></li>
</ul>
```

problem can be seen here: 
http://billedeupload.dk/?v=FcSx.png

I want it to look like this:
http://billedeupload.dk/?v=wSQfe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center your background i guess it's your image:

```
.login {
  background-position: 10px center;
}
```

The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical.